# Making a button toggle once a day

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to implement something in my Android application along these lines:

1. On any certain day if a user opens the app then they click a button, which will increment a number +1. Then can also click that button again which will put the number back to what it was so the number -1.
2. They can only do this once a day, so at most the number will be +1 from what it was before. But the user can click it and unlick it as many times as they want, it will only still be adding max +1 to the number.

I currently have something implemented: In my database I have a object for updatedTime. I then use a function to check if its on the same day:

```
private boolean isSameDay(int position){
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Date updatedDate = mDataSource.get(position).getUpdated();
    // Strip out the time part of each date.
    int MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long julianDayNumber1 = currentDate.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
    long julianDayNumber2 = updatedDate.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;

    // If they now are equal then it is the same day.
    return julianDayNumber1 == julianDayNumber2;
}
```

Which checks if it's the same day so user can't click on it again. Now I am stumped on figuring out how to make it toggleable so the user can click it again but it will just decrement it, and then user can click it again and it will increment it and so on, until the next day.

This is my `OnClickListener` for the button, not sure how to implement the toggle function.

```
habitChecked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("In on Click:", ""+position+"");
            updateHabit(position);
        }
    });
```

And this is my updateHabit method:

```
private void updateHabit(int position){
    Realm.init(mContext);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    if(!isSameDay(position)){ //If the habit hasn't already been updated today
        mDataSource.get(position).setTracker(mDataSource.get(position).getTracker()+1);
        mDataSource.get(position).setUpdated(new Date()); //update updated date
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

To summarize: The current functionality is that the user can only click the button once a day which adds the +1, but can't "unclick" it to undo the click and increment, and then reclick it if they want to.

Any help would be appreciated and I can supply any other code that might be relevant.

Comment: when the user clicks, add that to the DB. your server code can remove it the following day. when the user loads the app, do a query, if they ARE in the DB, the button is disabled.... if they arent, its enabled. ....Maybe i understand your flow...

Comment: No sorry its supposed to let the user click and unclick as many times they want to, but each day the number will only be updated +1 at max. So if i open the app and its a new day, i should click it and it goes +1, and then unlick it and it does -1, and then reclick it does +1 etc. Until the next day and then same thing again. Basically lets users add +1 to the number each day, but also lets them "undo" a add.

Comment: ok. so you start the activity..... i click the button which has a value of 0? I tap it, it goes to 1. I then tap it again, it goes to -1. then back to 1, -1, 1, -1..... at that point why does it matter what day it is? lol. Seems like that wouldnt matter at all. I can sit there and tap this buttont 208572034986290385 times and just go 1 -1  1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1

Comment: So almost, basically what happens is say i open app and you make new item, its at 0 by default. You click the button once it goes 1, u click it again it goes back to 0 (hence the -1), you can keep doing it all day TODAY and it will go from 0, to 1, but say you left it at 1. Tomorrow you open the App and its at 1. You click the button it puts it to 2. Then the next day you click it its at 3, but you realized you clicked it by accident, or whatever, and you click it at leave it 2. Next day again it starts at 2, and you can add or do nothing. Its for tracking habits, to see if you did it or not.

Comment: Why can't you have two different counters. One for toggling between 1 and 0 and another to count the days?

Comment: Can you explain further, how should I go about counting the days, to make sure its a new day and to check the counts? Thanks!